# Flexslider - Carousel images aren't scrolling like expected

Tags: slider, carousel, flexslider

I have a website http://www.raggeddaisy.com where I have implemented the Flexslider utility.  On my Default page, The Slider images are scrolling correctly, however, the Carousel images underneath aren't scrolling in combination with the Slider image.    As the Slider image scrolls correctly, the carousel seems to jump four images at a time even though it doesn't highlight one of the images in the carousel that is visable.

This same piece of code (minus the actual images) is duplicated on my http://www.raggeddaisy.com/MagneticBoards.csthml page and the slider images work perfectly.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is behaving differently on the two pages?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    itemWidth: 100,
    itemMargin: 0,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    sync: "#carousel",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the move attribute (number of slides that the slider should move) to the carousel, like this.

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    itemWidth: 100,
    itemMargin: 0,
    asNavFor: '#slider',
    move: 1 // ADDED
});
```

Comment: This has partially helped.  It has forced the carousel to move one at a time instead of jumping four images on the first slide transition.

Comment: The problem now is that I have 8 slides in the carousel/slider, with four images displayed in the carousel.The carousel seems to work and transition and slide to the first 5 images.  However, when the slider goes to the 6th image, the carousel just stays displaying images 2 through 5.  It does not slide and display the 7th or 8th slide in the carousel automatically.  I can force display the last two images in the carousel using the navigation arrows.  But, it is like the carousel has lost it's sync with the #slider.